# SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services: Reports are Compressed

Tags: sql-server-2005, web-applications, reporting-services, cross-browser

I have a report that I am capable of viewing correctly in Internet Explorer (IE) with the help of Reports from SQL Server 2005 Report Server (SSRS). The problem is that the report is compressed to about 100px by 100px in Firefox and probably other browsers such as Safari and Chrome. Also, I am using IIS6.

How can a report be rendered properly in browsers other than IE with SSRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a firefox issue it is a MS issue with how they developed reporting services (the web based portal to access your reports).  It is not compliant with some rules of the Web community, hence the issues you see.  The issue pertains to the usage of iFrames.  In firefox the iFrame's height has a small default value.  In Internet Explorer, iFrames automatically resize based on a document's height.  Not so clever.

See this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1135437.aspx

As well as this: http://blog-mstechnology.blogspot.com/2009/08/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs.html

Mainly this:

To Fix the Issue in Firefox, hope any one the following 2 ways will help us.

Step1:

1. Go to the following Location, where SQL Server is installed
   ..\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages
2. Open ReportViewer.aspx File
3. add the style property marked in bold and blue color, Then try this
   style="display:table; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden" ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" />

If not Helps the first step, then try the step 2.

Step2:

ADD the following code to the ReportingServices.css file (by default, it's found in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles\"):

.DocMapAndReportFrame{ min-height: 860px;}

If you want Width also, then use this code

.DocMapAndReportFrame
{
min-height: 860px;
min-width: 1000px;
}

Comment: I've already tried what is proposed in the second link you provided. Sadly, it does not work. The first link has some interesting ideas. Some ideas look more like a patch than an actual solution, but at this point I'll will try anything! Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Alerty, this patch doesn't always work.  There are several .config files you have to fix.  The one posted on that link mentions one.  Also once you do make the change you have to recycle the apppool and the site that is hosting your reporting server web page.

Comment: @Alerty - the fix is just a workaround.  The best way out of this is not to use the hideous web site to display your reports.  Just create a container (a div) and you can add your reports to your own page.  Then when viewing the report simply use the URL http://pathToYourRSServer/reportserver/YourReport...
to access the actual contents of your report in a full browser window.

Comment: For the moment, I am not at my job so I can't have a look. The problem is that the report itself is apparently in a iFrame so I do not know if using the URL will change much. None the less thanks for the suggestion. I will try that when I can.

Comment: In the first link there is someone that says that he downloaded and installed Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005 SP1. This could do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I did following to ReportViewer.aspx and that help me Resolve the issue...

```
    <body style="display:table; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; height:100%;">
    <form runat="server" ID="ReportViewerForm" style="height:100%;">
    <RS:ReportViewerHost style="display:table;" ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the form height to 95% in Pages > ReportViewer.aspx